# How to solve "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault " in wcf Communication Exception?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-services, security

i try to use remote dll over a wcf service in windows service any machine.But wcf service return to me this error:

**CommunicationException:An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.**

My wcf service working good. Also i calling my wcf service calling a PROCESS.dll. i am calling wcf service dynamically:

```
  public static ApplicationHostServiceClient CreateApplicationHostService()
        {
            try
            {
                int maxDifference = 300;
                WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
                binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
                CustomBinding myCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(binding); //CreateMultiFactorAuthenticationBinding(binding);

                // Set the maxClockSkew
                var security = myCustomBinding.Elements.Find();
                security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(maxDifference);
                security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(maxDifference);

                // Set the maxClockSkew
                var secureTokenParams = (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)security.ProtectionTokenParameters;
                var bootstrap = secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;
                bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(maxDifference);
                bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(maxDifference);

                // Update the binding of the endpoint
               // service.Description.Endpoints[0].Binding = myCustomBinding;




                EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(ProcessApplication.Serverparameters.BaseServiceHost + "/Service/ApplicationHostService.svc"));
                ApplicationHostServiceClient ser = new ApplicationHostServiceClient(myCustomBinding, endpoint);

                return ser;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

                ProcessApplication.Application.OnError("CreateApplicationHostService is not              succeeded.", "CreateApplicationHostService", exc);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

But Above error is occured. How to solve my security exception?

Comment: what is the value of maxDifference?

Comment: Can you try maxDifference below 10?

Comment: turn on wcf trace on both client and server to see more information http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx